# How to reference a DotnetStandard 2.0 library from another DotnetStandard library?

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

I have started a project to move some framework libraries targeting Dotnet 4.6.1 to DotnetStandard. I am using VS2017. I started with a relatively simple library which did not have any nuget references and only couple of classes. The approach I took was,

1. Create a new DotnetStandard 2.0 library project. Just to make sure I have a clean slate instead of manipulating the csproj file of the existing project.
2. Copy the code files from the old to the new project
3. Make any code changes required to make the new project build

This worked pretty smoothly. Now, I started with a second library that referenced the first one. I followed the same steps as mentioned above. At Step 3, however, I am hitting roadblock. I am unable to get the namespaces exposed by the first library in the second library, whatever I do. I have tried these,

1. Referenced the First project from the second project as Project Reference
2. Created a nuget package for the first project, hosted it in a local folder and installed the package in second project.

Both ways, I am unable to get the namespaces and classes from the first project.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I tried creating a dummy solution and tried creating two Dotnetstandard projects there. Project referencing worked fine there. So, to experiment, in my actual solution, I deleted the second project and created again. That somehow resolved my issue and I am able to successfully add nuget as well as project references now. Not sure what the problem was earlier.

Comment: I do this all over the place with NuGet packages and I'm not having problems. I set the build and package outputs to project-specific folders under a common network share, and set up that share as a NuGet source, and it just works. I even started out the same way, converting an existing Framework library to netstandard20 with exactly the same process you describe. Are you getting errors, or the `using` statements don't resolve, or what?

Comment: The using statements don't resolve. However, I also noticed that any nuget or project reference I add to the project shows up with a warning symbol under Dependencies. Any idea why and could it be related to the issue I am facing?

Comment: Unfortunately you usually have to grind through the logs to figure out what the warnings are about.